# Error : The security token included in the request is invalid - Windows Phone Using AWS SNS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, windows-phone-8.1, amazon-sns

I am using below code to register the device(Windows Phone) in AWS SNS as an endpoint in the application

```
CognitoAWSCredentials cognitoProvider = new CognitoAWSCredentials(UserId,
                       IdentitypoolID,
                       UnAuthRoleARN,
                       AuthRoleARN,
                       Region);

            AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(cognitoProvider.GetCredentials().AccessKey.ToString(),
                cognitoProvider.GetCredentials().SecretKey.ToString(), REgion); //provide credentials here

            var channelOperation = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

            CreatePlatformEndpointRequest epReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
            epReq.PlatformApplicationArn = ApplicationArn;
            epReq.Token = channelOperation.Uri.ToString();

            CreatePlatformEndpointResponse epRes = await sns.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(epReq);

            CreateTopicRequest tpReq = new CreateTopicRequest();

            SubscribeResponse subsResp = await sns.SubscribeAsync(new SubscribeRequest()
            {
                TopicArn = TopicArn,
                Protocol = "application",
                Endpoint = epRes.EndpointArn
            });
```

While create an endpoint it throws an error **The security token included in the request is invalid** while execute below code

```
CreatePlatformEndpointResponse epRes = await sns.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(epReq);
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to register a windows phone device in AWS SNS Application. I can create endpoint using the below code.

```
private async void Push()
        {
            CognitoAWSCredentials cognitoProvider = new CognitoAWSCredentials(UserId,
                   IdentitypoolID,
                   UnAuthRoleARN,
                   AuthRoleARN,
                   Region);

            using (var sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                var channelOperation = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

                CreatePlatformEndpointRequest epReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                epReq.PlatformApplicationArn = "PlatformApplicationARN";
                epReq.Token = channelOperation.Uri.ToString();

                CreatePlatformEndpointResponse epRes = await sns.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(epReq);

                CreateTopicRequest tpReq = new CreateTopicRequest();

                SubscribeResponse subsResp = await sns.SubscribeAsync(new SubscribeRequest()
                {
                    TopicArn = "TopicARN",
                    Protocol = "application",
                    Endpoint = epRes.EndpointArn
                });

                channelOperation.PushNotificationReceived += ChannelOperation_PushNotificationReceived;
            }
        }
```